# Properties of the line $"L"$ in the phrase "the line called $"L"$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ that consist of all scalar multiples of the vector $\vec x$"

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

If the line $L$in $\mathbb{R}^3$ consist of all the scalar multiples of the vector $\begin{bmatrix}4\\7\\5\end{bmatrix}$, is the line L parallel or perpendicular or neither parallel nor perpendicular to $\begin{bmatrix}4\\7\\5\end{bmatrix}$?

Answer (score 0):

If we call the vector $\mathbf{v}$, it's the line $p(\lambda) = \lambda \mathbf{v}$, i.e. the line going through the origin in the direction $\mathbf{v}$.  So parallel.